# How to set up a base url when using the Vue.js blueprint?

Tags: jhipster

I would like my app to run on /myapp instead of / but I can't seem to make that work.

I would like this to work when running the application as a jar, without running the client separately, and when running it from IntelliJ as a Spring Boot App (again, without running the client separately).

I have generated the application with JHipster and it was working fine on /

Then I did the following:

1. in application.yml

```
server.servlet.context-path: /myapp
```

2. in webapp/app/router/index.ts

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: '/myapp/',
  routes: [
    {
```

Now, when running the app and calling localhost:8080/myapp I get the error page telling "An error has occured :-(" and I can see that it's trying to call

http://localhost:8080/content/css/loading.css

http://localhost:8080/app/main.bundle.js

http://localhost:8080/app/global.bundle.js

http://localhost:8080/manifest.webapp

which all result in 404s.

What am I missing ?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The version html-webpack-plugin version is 3.2.0.

I tried making the change in webpack/webpack.common.js:

```
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
      chunks: ['vendors', 'main', 'global'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual',
      inject: true
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/myapp/' }),
```

but it didn't work, even after trying

```
npm run webpack:build
```

It only worked after I manually modified the index.html to

```
<base href="/myapp/" />
```

The next question is: can this be made dynamic ?

For example, when running the app in a Docker container, that I can pass the path as an environment parameter.

I can do it for Spring, but can it also be done for Vue ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to configure the `<base href="/" />` in index.html.  You can do this by setting the `base` config option for the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` in `webpack.common.js` or `webpack.prod.js` ([code from sample app](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-vuejs/blob/10491016a37320c36d017d84ee3cda787611717c/webpack/webpack.common.js#L112)). It is set to `/` by default:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  base: '/',
```

Change to:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  base: '/myapp/',
```

This was added to the blueprint in [this commit](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/commit/9251a20264adb6b6fecd888933a28e6907af6587).

---

If you want to use the context-path in `dev` with the BrowserSync setup, configure `webpack-dev-server` with:

- `publicPath: '/myapp/',`
- `contentBasePublicPath: '/myapp/',`
- Add `.map(path => '/myapp' + path)` to the end of `devServer.proxy[0].context` (the list of paths to proxy like `/api`). May be a better way to do this part but could not find it.

---

This is not configurable out-of-the-box for Docker containers through environment variables due to the fact the base href is replaced during the client build process. One possible solution here is to add a step to the [entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-vuejs/blob/10491016a37320c36d017d84ee3cda787611717c/src/main/jib/entrypoint.sh) to replace the base href in `/app/resources/static/index.html` with the context path (for example if `SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH` is set).

---

Note: If you are using `jhipster-vuejs` with a version of `html-webpack-plugin` v3.x, then upgrade `html-webpack-plugin` to v4.3.0, remove `<base href="/" />` from `index.html`, and remove `chunkSortMode: 'dependency'` [like here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-vuejs/commit/a08d8a64673905f9947ce2c76757f5065b3a3c79#diff-095ab25254f4b14e3b1b865c88de585cL80).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited my post to reflect what I have done following your reply. I would still like to know if I did something wrong regarding webpack and if it can be done dynamically. Thank you again.

Comment: I added some config for using it in dev and added a possible solution to change it dynamically.